# How can i sharp only an edge as in this video?

Tags: objects

In this video https://youtu.be/ltuD1wg9MoE?t=10s he sharp only an edge of the cube, how can i did it?

Comment: Do you mean Bevel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the edges (in edit mode) you wanna bevel
2. Press CTRL+B
3. Move your mouse to set the scale
4. Scroll your mouse wheel to increase or decrease the no.of cuts

[image: STEP 1]

[image: STEP 2]

[image: STEP 3]